# Difference between transfer/transferFrom and approveAndCall in cost

Tags: gas

Which of these functions cost less, computationally and in terms of gas usage?

Comment: Hi There, Could you please elaborate which framework you are using for the approveAndCall function?

Comment: They offer different functionality: approveAndCall is close to approve+transferFrom, transferFrom is more generic than transfer. Comparing them directly will not give you adequate information.

Answer (score 1):

This question is highly dependent on calling context.

If called from Solidity, transfers are a form of contract calls and gas/computational costs are highly dependent on the contract that is being called. Either could cost more.

If, however, you are making the call from a web3 framework outside of contract code (for example via truffle), then calls cost nothing from a gas perspective while transfers still incur gas costs. Computational costs will be similar in both off-chain and on-chain scenario.

More details on gas costs are available in this canonical table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6mRqkBz3iWcOlRem_mO09GtSKEKrAsfO7Frgx18pNU/edit#gid=0.

Answer (score 0):

In Ethereum gas cost is assumed as a measure of computational complexity, so computational complexity and gas cost are basically the same.  As long as there are different token contracts, gas cost of their invocations depend on complexity of their logic and no how efficient their implementation of this logic is.  Though, for simple case you basically need to count storage writes, because this is what the most gas is usually spent to.  In Ethereum, overwriting of zero value with non-zero in storage costs more than overwriting non-zero with non-zero.  AFAICR, the former costs 20K and the latter costs 5K gas.  Also, overriding non-zero value with zero triggers gas refund (15K gas AFAICR).

So, for simple transfer, token smart contract needs to reduce sender's balance (5K or -15K gas) and increase recipient's balance (5K or 20K gas).  Together with intrinsic transaction cost (21K gas) this makes [21K](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcba9fd6d9f8e7dc7acc7472bf3fa7018a91495b1eec9e2b2e25b6751521d7548), [31K](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3e69dc1513cd6481b029c923ce62a260297f787bc2746ac0bce4b3ab0137346c) and [46K](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa74954e9d02641cde4b78307d2c85a298a5603cee8f5c2bfe7e953536d6ae748) gas for updating storage.

For `transferFrom`, token smart contract needs to  update spender's allowance as well (5K or -15K gas), which makes 21K to 52K gas for updating storage.

For `approveAndCall`, token contract need to first set allowance (5K or 20K gas), and then called contract will need to invoke `transferFrom`.  Though, called contract will most probably use all the allowance, thus triggering refund 15K gas.